# Binding array in PDO

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

We have some array of values that want to insert them to the database.

for example:

```
$first_Names = array("Bob","John","Paolo","Jack", "Alex");
$last_Names = array("Charlton", "Smith", "Maldini", "Rooney", "anotherlastname");
```

Now I want to insert them to database

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO people(fname, lname) VALUES(:fname, :lname)";
```

Can I bind array directly without using foreach command and insert them one by one items?

Comment: why do you want to do it *without using foreach*? using a `foreach()` where you `->bind()` and `->execute()` is very simple.

Comment: You'll need to add placeholders for every value, but yes you should be able to. You can build an array of all values and pass it to the `execute`.

Comment: @Sean yes, without foreach

Comment: but why? is this a homework assignment that you can't use `foreach()`? why avoid a simple method?

Comment: @sean No it's not homework, I'm searching to higher performance

Comment: as @chris85 mentioned, you could add more placeholders -> `$sql = "INSERT INTO people(fname, lname) VALUES(:fname0, :lname0), (:fname1, :lname1), ... ";` and then bind/execute all together -> `$dbh->execute(array(":fname0"=>$first_Names[0],":lname0"=>$last_Names[0], ":fname1"=>$first_Names[1],":lname1"=>$last_Names[1],....));`. but not sure if that would meet your  *higher performance* that you are searching for (as the overhead for a simple `foreach()` is nominal).

Comment: @Sean I use this inevitably